# How to return exact match on first element in the list

Tags: python, regex

- I have list I need to append the into another list which matches
- The exact match should come at first
- then it matches related matched
- if a = ['mnoabc', 'defabc', 'abc', 'abcdef', 'ijk', 'lmn'] I am searching 'abc' then 'abc' should come first then 'abcdef', then 'mnoabc', 'defabc'
- Not worried ordering of about mnoabc', 'defabc'.  if 'abc' is coming at start of the string then it should append to list at beginning

```
a = ['mnoabc', 'defabc', 'abc', 'abcdef', 'ijk', 'lmn']
m = []
for i in a:
    if 'abc' in i:
        m.append(i)
m
```

My out>> ['mnoabc', 'defabc', 'abc', 'abcdef']

Expected >> [ 'abc', 'abcdef','mnoabc', 'defabc']

- Do i need to do regex for this?

Comment: You need to explain the logic behind choosing which are "better" matches after you've completed the exact matches. I don't think regex is a good match for this... I think you are going to need to program some logic based on how you respond to my first sentence.

Comment: As I assume this a general question for multiple lists, what is the logic behind mnoabc before defabc?

Comment: @marcel, I am not worried about mnoabc', 'defabc, if 'abc' is coming at start of the string then it should append to list at begining

Comment: @j1-lee  I am expecting first 'abc' then 'abcdef', expected is  >> [ 'abc', 'abcdef','mnoabc', 'defabc']
its not a problem for 'mnoabc' and 'defabc' because 'abc' is coming in between

Answer (score 3):

You can use `insert` to insert an item at a specified position. Try the following:

```py
a = ['mnoabc', 'defabc', 'abc', 'abcdef', 'ijk', 'lmn']

m = []
num_startswith = 0

for i in a:
    if i == 'abc':
        m.insert(0, i)
        num_startswith += 1
    elif i.startswith('abc'):
        m.insert(num_startswith, i)
        num_startswith += 1
    elif 'abc' in i:
        m.append(i)

print(m) # ['abc', 'abcdef', 'mnoabc', 'defabc']
```

The variable `num_startswith` keeps track of where to insert a word that starts with `abc`.